# Can a 'regular' Folium tooltip show information dynamically?

Tags: python, folium, tooltip

I've worked previously with Folium's [`GeoJSONTooltip`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip) class and it works well for the choropleth maps that I make.

For a separate project, I'm wanting to utilize Folium's regular (i.e., not using a GeoJSON) [`map.Tooltip`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.map.Tooltip) class. But based on the documentation, it doesn't appear that a tooltip of this class can dynamically display information in the form of a tooltip - in other words, it looks like it can only show static text (the first parameter show in the documentation linked above). This obviously seems pretty useless, but I can't find examples where this class is used to show dynamic tooltip labels.

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What will be the source of the "dynamic" data?

Comment: The source of the data would be a time-series 'style' dictionary used to generate at TimeSliderChoropleth, as shown in the documentation here: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.TimeSliderChoropleth

Comment: I can't access that site, but you may need to write some additional steps to emulate Leaflet's and subsequently Javascript's handling of events within a map. It is not impossible, but can be tricky. Have a look at the jinja library, and how to create a template that can be embedded into a folium map to insert some additional Leaflet functions.